# Notice: Undefined index: itemid in C:\xampp\htdocs\lfms\deletei.php on line 3

Tags: php, crud

```
<?php
require('db.php');
$itemid=$_REQUEST['itemid'];
$query = "DELETE FROM lfmstable WHERE itemid=$itemid"; 
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die ( mysqli_connect_error());
header("Location: tables.php"); 
?>
```

I'm new to php and I can't seem to make the "Delete" button from my table work. I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: Can you share the code of portion from where you are sending this `itemid`...if you are trying to delete your item like `url/ifms/deletei.php?itemid=1` then try to use `$_GET['itemid']`

Comment: <?php
 require_once 'db.php';
 $con->query("DELETE FROM `lfmstable` WHERE `itemid` = 
    '$_REQUEST[itemid]'") or die(mysqli_error());
 header('location: tables.php'); I changed my code to this and now whenever i click the delete button, it doesn't do anything